# How do I inject a managed bean into @Component Spring class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring class annotated with @Component annotation.  And I need inject a bean into a local variable. How do I inject a managed bean or an EJB var into @Component Spring class?

```
@Component
public class AppInternetAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, Serializable {

    private IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO;

    public void setAutenticacaoBO(IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO) {
        this.autenticacaoBO = autenticacaoBO;
    }

    public AppInternetAuthenticationProvider() {

    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
// I need inject here
```

Comment: Is your `IAutenticacaoBO` managed by `Spring`?

Comment: It's a interface used to inject a field declared in 'spring-security.xml'.

Comment: If so then, answer from @ced-b should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your context is set up for annotation configuration and the bean you are trying to inject is the `IAutenticacaoBO` you just need to add an `@Autowired` annotation before the setter.

```
@Autowired
public void setAutenticacaoBO(IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO) {
```

As a matter of fact you do not necessarily need the setter at all you could just add the `@Autowired` annotation before the private attribute.

```
@Autowired
private IAutenticacaoBO autenticacaoBO;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three types I am aware of, where `@Autowired` is just before the mentioned member:

1. Field injection
2. Setter injection
3. Constructor injection

Field injection is discouraged, IDEs like IDEA moan here.
Setter injection is a little tricky because it is possible to introduce recursions, therefore I go with Constructor injection. 
With Spring >5 (or >4.3.x ?) you don't need `@Autowired` anymore, it'll all happen magically.